# ValueError: bad input shape (560, 5) sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, sklearn-pandas, model-fitting

I am starting to write the learning machine model. I have a Y_train dataset containing the labels where there are 5 classes. The X_train dataset contains the samples. I try to make my model with the help of a logistic regression.

X_train ((560, 20531)) and Y_train ((560, 5)) have the same dimensions.

I have seen a few publications associated with the same problem but I have not been able to solve the problem.
I don't know how to correct this error,can you help me please ?

```
X = pd.read_csv('/Users/lottie/desktop/data.csv', header=None, skiprows=[0])
Y = pd.read_csv('/Users/lottie/desktop/labels.csv', header=None)

Y_encoded = list()
for i in Y.loc[0:,1] :
    if i == 'BRCA' : Y_encoded.append(0)
    if i == 'KIRC' : Y_encoded.append(1)
    if i == 'COAD' : Y_encoded.append(2)
    if i == 'LUAD' : Y_encoded.append(3)
    if i == 'PRAD' : Y_encoded.append(4)
Y_bis = to_categorical(Y_encoded)


#separation of the data
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y_bis, test_size=0.30, random_state=42)

regression_log = linear_model.LogisticRegression(multi_class='multinomial', solver='newton-cg')

X_train=X_train.iloc[:,1:]

#train model
train_train = regression_log.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

Comment: What exactly is your `X_train` exactly? It looks like at first glance that you're inverting your number of samples with your number of features. Try `X.shape` and `Y.shape` and tell me what the console gives.

Comment: X_train contains for each line (=samples) contains values for each data.

Y_train: contains for each sample the associated class. X.shape : (801, 20532) and Y.shape (801, 2)

Comment: In all fairness, X and Y should have the same number of lines, which is consistent. X looks weird. How come you have 20532 features?

Answer (score 0):

You get that error because your label is categorical. You need to use a label encoder to encode it into 0,1,2.. , check out [help page from scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing_targets.html). Below would be an implementation using an example dataset similar to yours:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()

Y = pd.DataFrame({'label':np.random.choice(['BRCA','KIRC','COAD','LUAD','PRAD'],560)})
X = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(0,1,(560,5)))

Y_encoded = le.fit_transform(Y['label'])

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y_encoded, test_size=0.30, random_state=42)

regression_log = linear_model.LogisticRegression(multi_class='multinomial', solver='newton-cg')

X_train=X_train.iloc[:,1:]

train_train = regression_log.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```